Dealing with a very large xarray dataset: loading slices consuming too much time
I have a very large netcdf dataset consisting of daily chunks data from April 1985 to April 2024. As the arrays are divided into daily chunks, I often open them by using ds = xr.open_mfdataset(*.nc). The entire dataset has up to 1.07TB, which is way way far than I can handle loading into memory:

By slicing over lat/lon coordinates ds.sel(latitude=y, longitude=x, method='nearest') I get a single pixel along my timeseries, which is now far lighter than the original dataset and allows me to perform the analysis I need:

However, even though the sliced dataset is now very light, it stills takes so much time for it to get loaded into memory (more than 1h) with ds.load(). This would not be a big deal if I didn't need to perform this operation more 100,000 times, which would take incredible 10 years to finish!
I don't have a powerful machine, but it's decent enough for performing the tasks I need. Although I was expecting this task to took some time, I really wish to finish it before becoming a dad. Besides going for a more powerful machine (which I think will still not reduce the amount of required time to the order of days), is there any way I can try to optimize this task?

The problem is that the sliced result still requires many operations. On the screenshot you shared, the "Dask graph" field still has a large number of layers and chunks.
Possible ways forward include:

using chunks kwarg to select the most appropriate chunking. Rough guess:

import dask
import xarray as xr


ds = xr.open_mfdataset(*.nc, chunks={"time": 15_000})
slice = ds.sel(latitude=y, longitude=x, method='nearest')
slice.compute()


paying a fixed cost in terms of time/disk space and reshaping the data into the format/chunks most compatible with your workflow;

trying dask.optimize, rough pseudocode:


import dask
import xarray as xr


ds = xr.open_mfdataset(*.nc)
slice = ds.sel(latitude=y, longitude=x, method='nearest')
(optimized_slice,) = dask.optimize(slice)
optimized_slice.compute()


Thank you very much. I'm trying to work this around by applying your suggestions, but couldn't find a reasonable solution yet. I want to point out, however, that all my nc files were compressed with zlib when saved. I thought compressed files would only affect the opening time with xr.open_mfdataset(), but could this be the reason for such a long time for loading the slices into memory as well?

Hmm, yes, dask/xarray would need to decompress every time the file is read, so that will add to the processing time.

Makes so much sense now. I shall try rewriting my nc files without zlib compression, I think it will substantially speed up the task. Thank you!

I can confirm that loading uncompressed files reduced the required time by more than 4x! However, it's still not reasonable since I have to repeat this task 100,000 times more. I will keep studying your suggestions and try to improve the parallelism in my code. I feel the easiest way to deal with this will be to subset my dataset into smaller lat/lon domains so I can directly load them into memory when opening. As almost half of my dataset are mask values (i.e. nan), subsetting into smaller domains might be a good idea...

Since I was able to solve my problem by subsetting my large dataset into smaller domains and then loading them directly into memory, I'll close this issue. Thank you very much @SultanOrazbayev for your suggestions, they were very helpful.

Great to know, @GabrielLucas!
